# Where are epub files stored?

Tags: epub

I have this old epub file on my phone that I'm trying to download but I have no idea where it's stored. The app I used was Lithium. I can read it fine on lithium but it won't show up anywhere else. Lithium doesn't give me an option to show file location either.

I tried installing other epub readers but none of them can locate the specific epub I want to get. Does anyone know where epub files are stored on android?

Comment: How was the epub file copied on your phone? By the Lithium app itself?

Comment: Usually, the file is inside the app's data folder that can't be accessed by other apps, and as a user, needs root access to access it.

Comment: Thank you guys. At this point it seems more trouble than its worth to get to it.